# Public initializer not available outside of struct

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing my first Swift package, which contains a structure like this:

```swift
public struct XYDocument: FileDocument, Codable {
    // properties

    public init(...) {
        // memberwise initializer
    }

    public init(_ file: FileWrapper) throws {
        guard let data = file.regularFileContents else {
            throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
        }
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
    }

    public init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        try self.init(configuration.file) // this works fine
    }

    // public func fileWrapper ...
}
```

Now, as soon as I'm trying to do this outside of the package, the initializer does not seem to be available:

```swift
let file = try FileWrapper(url: request.fileURL)
let document = try XYDocument(file) // ERROR: No exact matches in call to initializer
```

What am I not getting here?

Comment: Just a guess: Is there any chance that `FileWrapper(url:)` returns an optional `FileWrapper`?

Comment: @lazarevzubov That's what I thought, too. But that's not the reason. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filewrapper/1415658-init

Comment: To be sure add `print(type(of: file)` before the call to the initializer

Comment: do you have other code or package that also declare a (different) `XYDocument`?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Reasonable assumption, but no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error, I figured out why it didn't work. The reason was hidden in that part of the code that I have (conveniently) omitted from the question.

```swift
public struct XYDocument: FileDocument, Codable {
    var date: Date
    var prop: Float // The implementation details don't matter

    public init(date: Date = Date(), prop: Float = 0.0) {
        self.date = date
        self.prop = prop
    }
    ...
}
```

Perhaps the solution would have been obvious if I had included the declaration of the memberwise initializer. For some (to me incomprehensible) reason, the other initializer wasn't recognized, no matter how I labeled the parameter (such as `init(fileWrapper: FileWrapper)` instead of `init(_ file: FileWrapper)`) as long as all parameters of the first initializer had default values.

Now, it is declared as `public init(date: Date, prop: Float)` and the compiler error is gone.